# Masstransit, RabbitMQ, multiple consumers with multiple instances

Tags: rabbitmq, masstransit

I have a single producer that publishes some kind of event. Then i have two different services that both should consume that event and process it somehow. Both of these services have multiple instances and i want to make it so only a single instance of each service would consume the event (see the picture for clarity).

Is there any way i can achieve that with Masstransit configuration or manual configuration of RabbitMQ queues is the only way?

[image: event consumation scheme]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use different endpoint names (queues) for each of the services. Each queue will get its own binding to the typed message exchange and get its own copy.

Service instances will use the same queue name as all the other instances, so only one instance will get a message.

It's basic pub-sub, which is described in details in the [documentation](https://masstransit-project.com/usage/producers.html#publish).

Comment: Thanks! Explicit queue names were the bit i was missing!

Comment: We even mentioned it here https://masstransit-project.com/troubleshooting/common-gotchas.html#sharing-a-queue